# timezone offset included

Tags: php, date, timezone

You know we can use `date()` with number of seconds. for example `date('H:i:s', 3652)`.
But it returns wrong string if I set a timezone for dates:

```
date('H:i:s', 1); // it should returns '00:00:01'
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Rome');
date('H:i:s', 1); // it returns '01:00:01'. 3600s plus!
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Europe/Rome timezone is GMT+1.  It's returning the time in Rome at the Epoch (one hour ahead of GMT), so it's correct.

Comment: yes it is, but I want seconds in H:i:s format exactly; no offset included.

Comment: Do you just want to calculate the number of hours, minutes, and seconds a number of seconds equals?  For example, what should 86401 return?  Should it return 00:00:01 or should it return 24:00:01?  If your answer is the former then you can just use date() but set the timezone to UTC.  If your answer is the latter then `date()` is not correct and you need to write a function to do the math of converting seconds to hours, minutes, and remainder of seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution!

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Rome');
$offset = date('Z');
date('H:i:s', 1 - $offset); // it returns '00:00:01' now.
```

at all, as Crashspeeder said, a function to convert seconds to hours, min, sec is better. because it supports seconds more than 86400.